# nativescript-sms-receiver event onSMSReceived never occurs but the others do how to manage it?

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

**The timeout event occurs but the onSMSReceiver (an event too) never work. I tried to get the message from an alert but I don't arrive to make it work till now** .
I have also add the code to the AndroidManifest.xml file.
The link of the module I used :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sms-receiver

The code below to show you :

```
const smsreceiver=require("nativescript-sms-receiver").SmsReceiver;

var messages="";
exports.onTap=function(){
    console.log("It's working +++++++");
    createViewModel.set("status"," ON ");

 smsreceiver.getInstance().registerListeners(
     function () {
         // onSMSReceiverStarted
        alert("Starting listenning to the sms ");//I get this message

     }.bind(this),
     function (exception) {
         // onSMSReceiverFailed
         alert("There is an exception");

     }.bind(this),
     function (message) {
         //onSMSReceived
         createViewModel.set("status",message);
            alert(message);
            messages=message; 
             // handle sms here
            alert("Received message");//This part never works 
            alert("The message is :"+message);

         // deregister Sms Listener to avoid invalid operations
        // smsreceiver.getInstance().deregisterListeners();
     }.bind(this),
     function () {
         // onSMSReceiverTimeOut
         alert(messages);
         alert("Sms received timeout ");//This message works
         //smsreceiver.getInstance().deregisterListeners();

     }.bind(this)
);

// start sms receiver for single message
smsreceiver.getInstance().startReceiver();
```

This for Register SMSBroadcastReceiver I add the code directly in my AndroidManfinest.xml file :

```
<receiver 
 android:name="com.pravinkumarputta.android.smsreceiver.SMSBroadcastReceiver" 
 android:exported="true">
         <intent-filter>
    <action 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
         </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: What's onSMSReceiver? Have you implemented the broadcast receiver for SMS? Please share the complete code and add as much details as possible.

Comment: Yes I have registered the broadcast receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Which version / device model you are testing it with?

Comment: I tested it on android 8.1 .I was oblige to build the project an install it on a smartphone cause I can't send sms in the emulator

Comment: Did you try running the demo app in the plugin repo, produces same results?

Comment: Yes I tried it .It is almost the same results .The timeout event works , the onSMSReceiverStarted works but the one I want don't : onSMSReceived ...

Comment: I would suggest you to raise an issue in the plugin repo, the author uses his own library project within plugin. You might have to debug that to find where the issue lies exactly.